# How do I create word/tag cloud in obiee

Tags: oracle, analytics, oracle12c, obiee, word-cloud

Our company is using Oracle12c and recently wanted to see a list of the most used payment purposes in a form of word/tag cloud.

There is a column in a table that stores all payment purposes and the task is to know the frequency of these purposes and display them as a tag cloud in Obiee.

Is there any way to do this? Can Obiee analyze it itself or should I provide the word list to look for? If I should then it would be hard to accomplish since there are thousands of payments with thousands of different purposes.

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Mark Rittman wrote a blog piece on word tag clouds with OBIEE. It's for 11g but it should be transferable. [Check it out](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2010/12/oracle-bi-11g-word-tags-clouds/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I saw that post, he provides words to use in his source, but if I should provide it too then it would be very time consuming to find the words since there are thousands of different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

SampleApp 607 contains a working example:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html

Comment: Thank you, Chris, I will update as soon as I can download and test it